# How to create XACML policy and request single user having multiple roles in same resources or different resources

Tags: authorization, xacml, abac, alfa, wso2-identity-server

Create a XACML policy having multiple roles for single user and same resources and how to create request and access only one rule which roles and resources.

### The Data Model

- resources:- company
- roles:- admin(create and delete), visitor(read), tenant(update);
- user:- abc;

### Scenario

1. if user login in application with resource `"company"` and select `"admin"` role then create request and validate XACML policy rule and permit to (`create` and `delete`).
2. if user login in application with resource `"company"` and select `"visitor"` role then create request and validate XACML policy rule and permit to (`read`).
3. if user login in application with resource `"company"` and select `"tenant"` role then create request and validate XACML policy rule and permit to (`update`).

### Question

I only want sample of policy and request.
What type of XACML policy we create and What request we will send in XML format

Comment: This sounds a lot like homework... What have you tried so far? Which library are you using?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the policy you are looking for written in [alfa](/questions/tagged/alfa).

```js
namespace com.axiomatics.so.pankaj{    
/**
 * Company policy
 */
policyset company{
    target clause resource == "company"
    apply firstApplicable
    /**
     * Administrators can...
     */
    policy administrator{
        target clause role == "admin"
        apply firstApplicable
        /**
         * Create
         */
        rule create{
            target clause action == "create"
            permit
        }
        /**
         * Delete
         */
        rule delete{
            target clause action == "delete"
            permit
        }
    }
    /**
     * Visitors can...
     */
    policy visitor{
        target clause role == "visitor"
        apply firstApplicable
        /**
         * read
         */
        rule read{
            target clause action == "read"
            permit
        }
    }
    /**
     * Tenants can...
     */
    policy tenant{
        target clause role == "tenant"
        apply firstApplicable
        /**
         * Update
         */
        rule update{
            target clause action == "update"
            permit
        }
    }
}
```

}

You also need to define the attributes you will be using the policy

```js
attribute role{
    category = subjectCat
    id = "com.axiomatics.so.role"
    type = string
}
attribute resource{
    category = resourceCat
    id = "com.axiomatics.so.company"
    type = string
}
attribute action{
    category = actionCat
    id = "com.axiomatics.so.action"
    type = string
}
```

This leads to the following XACML policy in XML

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><!--This file was generated by the 
    ALFA Plugin for Eclipse from Axiomatics AB (http://www.axiomatics.com). --><!--Any modification to this file will 
    be lost upon recompilation of the source ALFA file -->
<xacml3:PolicySet
    PolicyCombiningAlgId="urn:oasis:names:tc:xacml:1.0:policy-combining-algorithm:first-applicable"
    PolicySetId="http://axiomatics.com/alfa/identifier/com.axiomatics.so.pankaj.company"
    Version="1.0"
    xmlns:xacml3="urn:oasis:names:tc:xacml:3.0:core:schema:wd-17">
    <xacml3:Description>Company policy</xacml3:Description>
    <xacml3:PolicySetDefaults>
        <xacml3:XPathVersion>http://www.w3.org/TR/1999/REC-xpath-19991116
        </xacml3:XPathVersion>
    </xacml3:PolicySetDefaults>
    <xacml3:Target>
        <xacml3:AnyOf>
            <xacml3:AllOf>
                <xacml3:Match
                    MatchId="urn:oasis:names:tc:xacml:1.0:function:string-equal">
                    <xacml3:AttributeValue
                        DataType="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#string">company</xacml3:AttributeValue>
                    <xacml3:AttributeDesignator
                        AttributeId="com.axiomatics.so.company"
                        Category="urn:oasis:names:tc:xacml:3.0:attribute-category:resource"
                        DataType="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#string"
                        MustBePresent="false" />
                </xacml3:Match>
            </xacml3:AllOf>
        </xacml3:AnyOf>
    </xacml3:Target>
    <xacml3:Policy
        PolicyId="http://axiomatics.com/alfa/identifier/com.axiomatics.so.pankaj.company.administrator"
        RuleCombiningAlgId="urn:oasis:names:tc:xacml:1.0:rule-combining-algorithm:first-applicable"
        Version="1.0">
        <xacml3:Description>Administrators can...</xacml3:Description>
        <xacml3:PolicyDefaults>
            <xacml3:XPathVersion>http://www.w3.org/TR/1999/REC-xpath-19991116
            </xacml3:XPathVersion>
        </xacml3:PolicyDefaults>
        <xacml3:Target>
            <xacml3:AnyOf>
                <xacml3:AllOf>
                    <xacml3:Match
                        MatchId="urn:oasis:names:tc:xacml:1.0:function:string-equal">
                        <xacml3:AttributeValue
                            DataType="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#string">admin</xacml3:AttributeValue>
                        <xacml3:AttributeDesignator
                            AttributeId="com.axiomatics.so.role"
                            Category="urn:oasis:names:tc:xacml:1.0:subject-category:access-subject"
                            DataType="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#string"
                            MustBePresent="false" />
                    </xacml3:Match>
                </xacml3:AllOf>
            </xacml3:AnyOf>
        </xacml3:Target>
        <xacml3:Rule Effect="Permit"
            RuleId="com.axiomatics.so.pankaj.company.administrator.create">
            <xacml3:Description>Create</xacml3:Description>
            <xacml3:Target>
                <xacml3:AnyOf>
                    <xacml3:AllOf>
                        <xacml3:Match
                            MatchId="urn:oasis:names:tc:xacml:1.0:function:string-equal">
                            <xacml3:AttributeValue
                                DataType="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#string">create</xacml3:AttributeValue>
                            <xacml3:AttributeDesignator
                                AttributeId="com.axiomatics.so.action"
                                Category="urn:oasis:names:tc:xacml:3.0:attribute-category:action"
                                DataType="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#string"
                                MustBePresent="false" />
                        </xacml3:Match>
                    </xacml3:AllOf>
                </xacml3:AnyOf>
            </xacml3:Target>
        </xacml3:Rule>
        <xacml3:Rule Effect="Permit"
            RuleId="com.axiomatics.so.pankaj.company.administrator.delete">
            <xacml3:Description>Delete</xacml3:Description>
            <xacml3:Target>
                <xacml3:AnyOf>
                    <xacml3:AllOf>
                        <xacml3:Match
                            MatchId="urn:oasis:names:tc:xacml:1.0:function:string-equal">
                            <xacml3:AttributeValue
                                DataType="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#string">delete</xacml3:AttributeValue>
                            <xacml3:AttributeDesignator
                                AttributeId="com.axiomatics.so.action"
                                Category="urn:oasis:names:tc:xacml:3.0:attribute-category:action"
                                DataType="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#string"
                                MustBePresent="false" />
                        </xacml3:Match>
                    </xacml3:AllOf>
                </xacml3:AnyOf>
            </xacml3:Target>
        </xacml3:Rule>
    </xacml3:Policy>
    <xacml3:Policy
        PolicyId="http://axiomatics.com/alfa/identifier/com.axiomatics.so.pankaj.company.visitor"
        RuleCombiningAlgId="urn:oasis:names:tc:xacml:1.0:rule-combining-algorithm:first-applicable"
        Version="1.0">
        <xacml3:Description>Visitors can...</xacml3:Description>
        <xacml3:PolicyDefaults>
            <xacml3:XPathVersion>http://www.w3.org/TR/1999/REC-xpath-19991116
            </xacml3:XPathVersion>
        </xacml3:PolicyDefaults>
        <xacml3:Target>
            <xacml3:AnyOf>
                <xacml3:AllOf>
                    <xacml3:Match
                        MatchId="urn:oasis:names:tc:xacml:1.0:function:string-equal">
                        <xacml3:AttributeValue
                            DataType="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#string">visitor</xacml3:AttributeValue>
                        <xacml3:AttributeDesignator
                            AttributeId="com.axiomatics.so.role"
                            Category="urn:oasis:names:tc:xacml:1.0:subject-category:access-subject"
                            DataType="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#string"
                            MustBePresent="false" />
                    </xacml3:Match>
                </xacml3:AllOf>
            </xacml3:AnyOf>
        </xacml3:Target>
        <xacml3:Rule Effect="Permit"
            RuleId="com.axiomatics.so.pankaj.company.visitor.read">
            <xacml3:Description>read</xacml3:Description>
            <xacml3:Target>
                <xacml3:AnyOf>
                    <xacml3:AllOf>
                        <xacml3:Match
                            MatchId="urn:oasis:names:tc:xacml:1.0:function:string-equal">
                            <xacml3:AttributeValue
                                DataType="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#string">read</xacml3:AttributeValue>
                            <xacml3:AttributeDesignator
                                AttributeId="com.axiomatics.so.action"
                                Category="urn:oasis:names:tc:xacml:3.0:attribute-category:action"
                                DataType="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#string"
                                MustBePresent="false" />
                        </xacml3:Match>
                    </xacml3:AllOf>
                </xacml3:AnyOf>
            </xacml3:Target>
        </xacml3:Rule>
    </xacml3:Policy>
    <xacml3:Policy
        PolicyId="http://axiomatics.com/alfa/identifier/com.axiomatics.so.pankaj.company.tenant"
        RuleCombiningAlgId="urn:oasis:names:tc:xacml:1.0:rule-combining-algorithm:first-applicable"
        Version="1.0">
        <xacml3:Description>Tenants can...</xacml3:Description>
        <xacml3:PolicyDefaults>
            <xacml3:XPathVersion>http://www.w3.org/TR/1999/REC-xpath-19991116
            </xacml3:XPathVersion>
        </xacml3:PolicyDefaults>
        <xacml3:Target>
            <xacml3:AnyOf>
                <xacml3:AllOf>
                    <xacml3:Match
                        MatchId="urn:oasis:names:tc:xacml:1.0:function:string-equal">
                        <xacml3:AttributeValue
                            DataType="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#string">tenant</xacml3:AttributeValue>
                        <xacml3:AttributeDesignator
                            AttributeId="com.axiomatics.so.role"
                            Category="urn:oasis:names:tc:xacml:1.0:subject-category:access-subject"
                            DataType="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#string"
                            MustBePresent="false" />
                    </xacml3:Match>
                </xacml3:AllOf>
            </xacml3:AnyOf>
        </xacml3:Target>
        <xacml3:Rule Effect="Permit"
            RuleId="com.axiomatics.so.pankaj.company.tenant.update">
            <xacml3:Description>Update</xacml3:Description>
            <xacml3:Target>
                <xacml3:AnyOf>
                    <xacml3:AllOf>
                        <xacml3:Match
                            MatchId="urn:oasis:names:tc:xacml:1.0:function:string-equal">
                            <xacml3:AttributeValue
                                DataType="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#string">update</xacml3:AttributeValue>
                            <xacml3:AttributeDesignator
                                AttributeId="com.axiomatics.so.action"
                                Category="urn:oasis:names:tc:xacml:3.0:attribute-category:action"
                                DataType="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#string"
                                MustBePresent="false" />
                        </xacml3:Match>
                    </xacml3:AllOf>
                </xacml3:AnyOf>
            </xacml3:Target>
        </xacml3:Rule>
    </xacml3:Policy>
</xacml3:PolicySet>
```

### Sample Response & Request

```json
{
"Request": {
    "ReturnPolicyIdList": true,
    "AccessSubject": {
        "Attribute": [
            {
                "AttributeId": "com.axiomatics.so.role",
                "Value": "admin"
            }
        ]
    },
    "Resource": {
        "Attribute": [
            {
                "AttributeId": "com.axiomatics.so.company",
                "Value": "company"
            }
        ]
    },
    "Action": {
        "Attribute": [
            {
                "AttributeId": "com.axiomatics.so.action",
                "Value": "create"
            }
        ]
    },
    "Environment": {
        "Attribute": []
    }
}
}
```

And the response

```json
{
  "Response" : {
    "Decision" : "Permit",
    "Status" : {
      "StatusCode" : {
        "Value" : "urn:oasis:names:tc:xacml:1.0:status:ok",
        "StatusCode" : {
          "Value" : "urn:oasis:names:tc:xacml:1.0:status:ok"
        }
      }
    },
    "PolicyIdentifierList" : {
      "PolicyIdReference" : {
        "Id" : "http://axiomatics.com/alfa/identifier/com.axiomatics.so.pankaj.company.administrator",
        "Version" : "1.0"
      },
      "PolicySetIdReference" : {
        "Id" : "http://axiomatics.com/alfa/identifier/com.axiomatics.so.pankaj.company",
        "Version" : "1.0"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks David for your reply. It helped me lot.

Comment: Can you tell me how to create API in WSO2API manager to access XACML policy from WSO2IS.

Comment: Unfortunately no. I can help with Axiomatics but not WSO2

Comment: Anyway. Thank you for your appropriate reply